# HDSPmixer and HDSPconf HiDPI Scaling Factor

Tags: gnome, 4k-monitor, hdpi

All -

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) with the Ubuntu Studio packages installed.  I'm working with a RME HDSP 9652 (Hammerfall) sound card and an ASUS HiDPI 32" screen. hdspmixer and hdspconf work as expected, but on my HiDPI screen I can barely read the text in hdspconf and the mixer in hdspmixer is practically unusable unless I hold a magnifying glass to the screen.  I cannot resize the windows, either.

I have gnome running at 200% via "Settings --> Display".  QT is at a factor of 2 for my photo editor (AfterShot) via `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=2` in .profile in ~.  Is there something similar I can do for hdspconf and hdspmixer?

Comment: Just because you're running Ubuntu Studio packages does not mean you're running Ubuntu Studio. This isn't an Ubuntu Studio issue at all.

Comment: I am unclear what issue it falls under but accepted your tag edit. However, if it was a GNOME issue, wouldn't the "Scale" setting @ 200% in "Displays" fix this?

And does that make this an application specific issue, a GUI environment issue (like QT), or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: `run_scaled` which is available here:
https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled

I copied and pasted the code into gedit and saved as "run_scaled" in my home directory.  Make the file executable:

```
chmod +X run_scaled
```

then

```
sudo apt install xvfb xpra
```

then

```
run_scaled hdspconf
```

and

```
run_scaled hdspmixer
```

Both apps are now useable, although they take a few seconds to load.  I've added the commands to Startup Applications:

Commands:

/home/myusername/run_scaled hdspconf

and

/home/myusername/run_scaled hdspmixer

Change *myusername* to your username.

They each take a few extra seconds to load after logging in, which is duplicated in the command line launch.

Cool script!  Thanks to Alexander Kauer (kaueraal).

Edit: this does leave 2 icons in the system tray, one for each application.  They could be useful...I get a whole Start menu to launch applications, plus options for scaling, and a lot more.